# Run Selection in VS code or ADS without cursor moving to the terminal afterwards

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I would like that the cursor stays in the script file after I run a code selection with F8. What setting should I change so the cursor does not move to the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)
for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Azure Data Studio (ADS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio) is installed, add the following line to your `settings.json` file (before the closing `}`):

```
  "powershell.integratedConsole.focusConsoleOnExecute": false,
```

Alternatively, use the settings GUI (press <kbd>Ctrl+,</kbd>):

[image: Settings GUI with relevant setting shown]

Note the GUI's convenient search feature: typing `powershell focus` was sufficient to locate the relevant setting.

Comment: Hi is this also possible in PowerShell ISE?

Comment: @xhr489, there's no standard option, but my guess is that you could author an add-on to do it. However, I suggest moving away from the ISE, because it is [no longer actively developed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+

Comment: Where is the stop buttom in Visual Studio, like the one in ISE?

Comment: @xhr489, in VS Code, while a script is running in the debugger, a floating toolbar is being displayed that has a Stop button, but please consider creating new question posts if you need additional assistance.